# Doing logistic regression in R with many variables (about 70)

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I know how to make an glm model in R when the number of variables is low (say less than 10 predictors).
Can anyone give me advise about how to do when the number of predictors is high? In this case I have about 70 variables. is there any package or algorithm to determine the best logistic regression model or at least some hint about how to determine which variable or interaction between then is good.

I could use some help in seeing what variables are of no use or little use. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Regards,
Gunnar

Comment: You may get better answers on https://stats.stackexchange.com/, but you could try using the package `glmnet` and use an elastic net regularized generalized linear model. This can take care of model selection for you in that one step as well. The vignettes should get you going.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Adam. Do you something lis this webpage shows: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/36-classification-methods-essentials/149-penalized-logistic-regression-essentials-in-r-ridge-lasso-and-elastic-net/

Comment: Yup. Something along those lines was what I was thinking.

Comment: take a look at the  [caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/) package also. It implements an interface with a lot of different models, including logistic regression, and an easy and straightforward way for cross-validation and variable selection.